# media query not working

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to use a couple stylesheets based on window size (phone or just very small desktop browser window). This works on neither. That is, I only see the style from 1024+.css Can someone help me out?

```
<!-- small display -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="resources/styles/small_device.css" />
<!-- widescreen -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/styles/1024+.css" />
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code works as intended - it loads the first stylesheet on small screens and **always** loads the `1024+.css` so the rules in the first stylesheet get overwritten every time.

Add a `media` query restriction for the larger screens as well

Comment: ah! yeah, okay. That makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Comment: Or if you were intending the 1024+ styles to be a "base" stylesheet you can simply move that above the one with the device media query.